# Styling the UL UL li not working on a dropdown

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

http://www.milknhny.co.uk/SofiaWork/

I'm trying to style the sub menu on this drop down, and ive tried a `ul ul` class, however it doesnt appear to be working.

I've had to do two specific stylings on the specific menu items (as the client wanted the first two a different color).

These are items:

```
#menu-item-10 etc.
```

Now do I style again specifics like `#menu-item-10 ul ul`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a specific selector;

```
li[id^="menu-item-"] ul ul
```

This way you match all menu-items, no matter how they end. `id` + `^=` selector means;

> everything in an id-attribute-field that starts with "string"

The `li` prefix will make it match only on `li`-elements.

Comment: hi Allendar, thankyou for this so much. So for example i have two menu items, #menu-item-6 being one, and i wish to style its submenu (which is currently visible as demolition.... would i do this? .headermenu ul li [id^="menu-item-6"] ul ul ?

Comment: also is it because of the specifics ive had to use (ie the menu-item-6) so that the usual .headermenu ul ul isnt working?

Comment: You can start deeper; `.menu li[id^="menu-item-"] ul li[id^="menu-item-"]` should match the first depth. You can traverse this each depth you go, the second depth would be; `.menu li[id^="menu-item-"] ul li[id^="menu-item-"] ul li[id^="menu-item-"]`. Because you chain the full path the style should search, it won't match just anything within `.menu` but only what you "full-path". Try playing around with it a bit. It's pretty nice once you get the hang of it.